# How to generate non-negative random numbers(integer) using RNGCryptoServiceProvider C#

Tags: random, rngcryptoserviceprovider

I need to generate non-negative random integers in my code. The example below generates integers;

```
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        // Buffer storage.
        byte[] data = new byte[4];

        // Ten iterations.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        // Fill buffer.
        rng.GetBytes(data);

        // Convert to int 32.
        int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

Ref: http://www.dotnetperls.com/rngcryptoserviceprovider
But it gives both positive and negative values. How do I generate only non-negative random integers?
I was earlier using Random.Next() which was giving me positive integers.

Comment: Why can you just take the absolute value of the result: `abs(value)` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp

Comment: I think that would create problem. Lets say the random no generator generates -2 and we will use the absolute value and use it as 2. Next it generates 2 and  the random number is still 2.

Comment: Well there are no guaranty two successive random numbers are different. What is the issue?

Comment: I have to use the random integer as the Msg Id of a snmp v3 packet. So, I think as you suggest I can use "abs" method to get the positive integer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, just use [`ToUInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in place of `ToInt32`

```
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    // Buffer storage.
    byte[] data = new byte[4];

    // Ten iterations.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    // Fill buffer.
    rng.GetBytes(data);

    // Convert to int 32.
    int value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple yet effective :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
repeat
  temp <- RNG.nextInteger();
until temp >= 0;
return temp;
```

Comment: I did not think of that..Its a good solution. But just a question. I read in MSDN forum that it takes more time to generate a random number using RNGCryptoServiceProvider, if I skip some random numbers for a positive one, won't it affect performance?

Comment: You are unlikely to notice the difference unless you are generating a very large number of random integers.  *Always* run a timing test before you declare something too slow.  A secure RNG is going to be slower than a non-secure RNG, no matter what you do.

Comment: I can't see how this would be better than taking the absolute value. Applying transformations to random numbers is a standard and adding a loop is extra complexity when simple arithmetic can do the job